# In Xamarin form, is it possible to do a databinding outside a listview, like just in a label?

Tags: forms, sqlite, xamarin, binding

Sorry for a bit confusing title.

I simply want to get my info from a db with a model. I know how I do it in a listview, but I cant seem to find information about doing it outside a listview. I know you can bind things to label, but then its just whats in my viewmodel.

Do I make any sense at all?

Thanks.

Update: I want to do this something like this listview

```
<ListView
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
        HasUnevenRows="True"
        IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
        IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MyProfile}"
        RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
        RefreshControlColor="Red"
        SelectionMode="None"
        SeparatorVisibility="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:MyProfile">
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                            <Frame CornerRadius="20" HasShadow="True">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
                                        <Label
                                        FontSize="Large"
                                        Text="{Binding Name}"
                                        VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                        <Label
                                        FontSize="Large"
                                        Text="{Binding id}"
                                        VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                        <Label
                                        FontSize="Small"
                                        Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}"
                                        VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

In a stacklayout with just labels:

```
        <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding MyProfile}"
             Orientation="Horizontal">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:MyProfile">
                    <controls:CircleImage Source="{Binding}"
                                  Aspect="AspectFill"
                                  WidthRequest="44"
                                  HeightRequest="44"
                                  ... />
                    <Label Text="Enter profile"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
```

I just want to update a label and not a list with info from db using data binding.

Comment: Yes, you can use databinding with almost any UI element, not just ListView.  But I'm not sure what you mean by "just whats in my viewmodel"?  What do you want to bind to that is NOT in your VM?  It would help a lot if you provided a concrete example of what you want to do.

Comment: I have a DB with with a table based on a model. I have created a VM that let me create new entries in this DB and retrieve them. When I want to retrieve them I use a Listview and are able to do a data bind, so when it calls my command, it populates in the listview. But i cant seem to do it outside the listview. I just want a simple label to show the specific info from the DB.  When I try to add "itemsource" to a stacklayout" It says Its not in its property.

Comment: please post some actual code that demonstrates what you are trying to do.

Comment: Posted some code. Do you understand me now?

Comment: Then How do I do it? While still using {Binding }? I cant sem to post code here in comment, But it seems like its working? What else do you think would be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But i cant seem to do it outside the listview. I just want a simple label to show the specific info from the DB. When I try to add "itemsource" to a stacklayout" It says Its not in its property.

According to your description, I guess that you want to display specific one record outside of ListView.

ListView is a view for presenting lists of data, especially long lists that require scrolling.

I do one sample that displaying one record selected by listview  outside of listview.

```
 <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <Image Source="{Binding selecteditem.source}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding selecteditem.Name}" />
        </StackLayout>
        <ListView
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding MyProfile}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding selecteditem}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Frame CornerRadius="20" HasShadow="True">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
                                        <Label
                                            FontSize="Large"
                                            Text="{Binding Name}"
                                            VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                        <Label
                                            FontSize="Large"
                                            Text="{Binding id}"
                                            VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                        <Label
                                            FontSize="Small"
                                            Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}"
                                            VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

 public partial class Page7 : ContentPage
{     
    public Page7()
    {
        InitializeComponent();                     
        this.BindingContext = new Profileviewmodel();
    }
           
}
public class Profileviewmodel:ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Profile> MyProfile { get; set; }
    private Profile _selecteditem;
    public Profile selecteditem
    {
        get { return _selecteditem; }
        set
        {
            _selecteditem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("selecteditem");
        }
    }
    public Profileviewmodel()
    {
        MyProfile = new ObservableCollection<Profile>();
        getdata();
    }
    private void getdata()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Profile profile = new Profile();
            profile.id = i.ToString();
            profile.Name = "the " + i + " profile";
            profile.PhoneNumber = "test " + i;
            profile.source = "c1.png";
            MyProfile.Add(profile);
        }
    }
}
public class Profile
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
}
```

The ViewModelBase is classt that implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, to update selecteditem value when listview selected index changed.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display data for a single object, you can do something like this

```
                         <Frame CornerRadius="20" HasShadow="True">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
                                    <Label
                                    FontSize="Large"
                                    Text="{Binding Name}"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                    <Label
                                    FontSize="Large"
                                    Text="{Binding id}"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                    <Label
                                    FontSize="Small"
                                    Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
```

and in the code behind for your page

```
// where MyViewModel is a single instance of the model you want to display
BindingContext = MyViewModel;
```